# Why is innovation spelt with 2 n's while renovation is spelt with 1?

Tags: spelling

Is there a consistent rule when you double the n's ?

Answer (score 13):

This has to with how these words are derived

> innovation = in + novation
>
> 1540-50; < Latin innovātus past participle of innovāre to renew, alter, equivalent to in- in-2 + novātus (novā(re) to renew, verbal derivative of novus new + -tus past participle suffix)

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/innovate

whereas

> renovation = re + novation
>
> 1400-50; late Middle English (adj.) < Latin renovātus (past participle of renovāre), equivalent to re- re- + nov(us) new + -ātus -ate1

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/renovate?s=t

so **innovation** has two *n*'s because the prefix and root both have *n*

Comment: Yes.  In-deed ...

Comment: You probably  need to refer to some etymological source  to support your answer.

Comment: ***Innovation:*** http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=innovation&allowed_in_frame=0 - ***Renovation:*** http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=renovation&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: @Andrew "Indeed" derives from "in deed" so roughly equivalent, but via Anglo-Saxon instead of Latin

Comment: A rule of thumb I learned is that, while suffixes often affect the spelling of the root word, prefixes (almost?) never do.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy That might be only partly true. In Latin, prefixes frequently affect the spelling of the root and we import them into English as-is